# Best way to insulate knee wall

Tags: insulation, attic

I have knee walls that have the insulation that is falling down.

As you can see in the images below, There is very little access behind the knee wall as there is duct work and cross braces in place that support the roof.

[image]
[image]

I was thinking about doing it in this order 
1) taking the knee wall drywall down 
2) installing blocking between joists with wood or foam board to create an air seal
3) insulating and air sealing the ceiling of the lower floor to up to the joist blocking
4) using furring strips on the backside of the knee wall to hold the insulation in place since getting sheathing back there would be nearly impossible
5) installing new insulation (foam or batts)
6) install new drywall

In the images below, there is ductwork, plumbing, and electrical that runs from the single story part of the house to the 2 story part of the house. The electrical continues between the joists between the upper and lower floors. What would be the best way to insulate this as well?

[image]

[image]